# Combining images with PHP GD

Tags: php, gd

I want to combine some images with PHPGD to create a CSS Sprite dynamically, though I have a problem. I haven't worked so much with GD and I barely managed to do it, but the problem is the images occupy much more space after I combine them.
I did a test with 3 images that have 13KB altogether. After I combine them the final result has 42.5KB.

Is there any solution to this without losing quality ?

Thanks

Comment: chances are you will want to combine the sprites outside of your webserver, as image manipulation functions are somewhat slow for production purposes.

Comment: I managed to do it and I will only have to combine 9 images a few times a day so it's not that much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well 13KB * 3 = 42 KB  thats right =)

maybe:
http://sheldon.lendrum.co.nz/php-gd-library-css-sprites_416/08/
or
something else?

there are many css sprite generators for php around (sourceforge ...)

Comment: Found the problem. I was taking jpeg images and saving the result as a high quality png, which increased the size dramatically.

Comment: well thats actually one reason  another is that there are more information in the new picture and its normal that such images are bigger, bout you should use just png so the server has not to work so hard to convert the pictures first